# importing multiple attributes and storing them into one alias

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I want to store all attributes into an alias

```
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } as icons from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

but `as` work only in single import

Comment: `const icons = { faCheckSquare, faCoffee }`

Answer (score 0):

Install needed packages

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

It works correct

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import * as icons from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={icons.faCoffee} />
```